# Split everything between two characters, including those (perl)

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I would like to use Perl's `split` functionality to do the following:

example string:

```
=foo>bar=\foo2>bar2=foo3> ...
```

Now I tried this:

```
@Array = split /=.*>/, $string
```

I'm expecting to get my array filled with `"bar", "bar2", ...`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your regex is so greedy it takes the whole string as the delimiter and you end up with nothing. But I don't understand how the splitting should work. What happens to `foo`? And is the `\` a `\f`, or a literal backslash?

Comment: how about this? split('=[^>]*>', $str). the first and last in the result will be empty.

Comment: Eyyyyy, sweet. Thanks alot! Works wonders, I'll just get rid of the empty array entries and that should be fine :)

Comment: `My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop? 4 answers` This answer doesn't matched with the OP asked.